# Como posso receber um input do usuario em Assembly (YASM/NASM x86 16bits) e o gravar inteiramente em DI?

Tags: assembly, nasm

estou com um problema no meu sistema operacional em assembly(x86) 16bits em que:

```
bits 16
org 7c00h
jmp sh
sh:
   putchar 13
   putchar 10
   putchar '>'
   putchar ' '
   readchar
   jmp sh
%macro putchar 1
   mov ah, 0eh
   mov al, %1
   int 10h
%endmacro
%macro readch 0
   xor ah, ah
   int 16h
%endmacro
%macro readchar 0
   ; não sei como poderia ser a implementação pois todas que faço o sistema operacional para de funcionar mesmo sem warring's ou erros
%endmacro
```